# Что такое проверяемый случай (test case) и отчёт об ошибке (bug report), в чём разница между ними?

Tags: тестирование

Как я понял `test case`*(что нужно проверить/выполнить - это наша задача определить и записать или нам пишут что необходимо проверить?)* состоит из ***Выполняемое действие (Action) – Ожидаемый результат (Expected result) – Фактический результат (Test result)***.

---

Но **bug report** имеет те же составляющие, только более обширен.

• Короткое описание (короткое описание проблемы).

• Серьезность (градация степени влияния на приложение ошибки).

• Приоритет (очередь исправления ошибки).

• Статус (отображает статус ошибки в своем жизненном цикле).

• Шаги воспроизведения (описание пути, который приводит к возникновению дефекта).

• Фактический результат (результат, к которому приходим выполнив все шаги воспроизведения).

• Ожидаемый результат (результат, который быть в соответствии с требованиями).

Comment: bug report - отчет об ошибке. test case - тестируемый случай. Пользователь или тестер шлет разработчику отчет об ошибке, после этого разработчик пишет тест, который покрывает этот случай. Баг репорт - это то как выглядит проблема с точки зрения пользователя. Тест кейс - как именно будет тестироваться, что проблема исправлена.

Comment: Если ожидаемый и фактический результаты совпали, то это не может быть баг-репортом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основное отличие между *проверяемым случаем* и *отчётом об ошибке* заключается в том, что первое является задачей, а второе есть итог её выполнения вместе с написанным для него отчётом, на основе которого будут ставиться уже новые задачи для тех, кто должен будет исправить найденные ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

**Тест-кейс** - сценарий проверки. Пошаговый сценарий, действия и ожидаемый результат после каждого из них.

```
Перейти по урлу stackoverflow.com - открылся сайт СО
Открыть вопрос из списка - урл изменился, виден текст вопроса
Написать и отправить ответ - ответ появился в списке ответов, рейтинг 0
Дождаться голоса за ответ - рейтинг ответа изменился с 0 на 1
и т.д.
```

**Отчёт об ошибке** - тоже пошаговый сценарий, но описываемые действия служат не для проверки работоспособности, а для гарантированного воспроизведения ошибки.

```
Открыть вопрос на СО
Написать в форму ответа текст `><script>alert('xss!')`
Нажать на кнопку отправки ответа
  Ожидаемый результат: ответ отправлен, текст ответа совпадает с тем, что был введён
  Актуальный результат: текст ответа не виден, в браузере появился алерт с текстом `xss!`
```

Как видите, в случае описания ошибки, все шаги, кроме последнего, вообще не содержат проверяемого результата. Зато последний шаг содержит и ожидаемый и фактический. И фактический явно указывает на ненормальное поведение.